# Parsing JSON effectively in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to extract a pair of values out of a JSON using dart

This is the function I have so far:

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "displayNames": [
        "John Doe",
        "Chloé Kamgang",
        "Lady Testing of Tarth"
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "uid": "1tcPRqNZ7wexX2DWa11V9Ay1zES2",
            "displayName": "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "uid": "aZg7Emp8H9W42irnM73NBdTe6YM2",
            "displayName": "Chloé Kamgang",
            "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/atalaku-fcf9e.appspot.com/o/Profilescaled_1e189635-0bc0-4791-ba20-6aded7ad3e8f7210544.jpg621jpg?alt=media&token=f5cffac3-a20c-4a83-8241-4fab16a9bd66"
        },
        {
            "uid": "hXzyTuDE8eafnSxITmz7ZdMQDnw1",
            "displayName": "Lady Testing of Tarth",
            "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/atalaku-fcf9e.appspot.com/o/Profilescaled_image_picker8162975920.jpg645jpg?alt=media&token=269007d1-09ee-4fe4-b7ad-72aa7cea756a"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the function:

```dart
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProfilesBySuggestion(
      String sSuggestion) async {
    try {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> listToReturn = [];
      if (sSuggestion == null ||
          sSuggestion.isEmpty ||
          !sSuggestion.startsWith('@')) return listToReturn;

      //Getting all the names
      Map<String, dynamic> listUsers = await getAllUsers();
      if (listUsers == null) return listToReturn;

      //Returning only the names corresponding
      List<dynamic> listNames = listUsers['displayNames'];
      for (String name in listNames)
        if (name
            .toLowerCase()
            .startsWith(sSuggestion.substring(1).toLowerCase())) {
          List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfusers = listUsers['users'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
          Map<String, dynamic> rightOne = listOfusers.firstWhere((user) => user['displayName'] == name);
          String sPhotoURL = rightOne['photoURL'];
          print('** name = $name, photoURL = $sPhotoURL');
          listToReturn.add({'name': name, 'photoURL': sPhotoURL});
        }
      return listToReturn;
    } catch (error) {
      print('*** Error During getProfilesBySuggestion: ${error.toString()}');
      return [
        {'errorMessage': error.toString()}
      ];
    }
  }
```

What I want is a list of pair (name, photoURL). I am using the flutter_typeahead plugin, I want to display a list of names and their respective avatars. As you can see, I am using Firebase. Please let me know if there is a better option as well, as this will get pretty heavy with scale. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point when working with data that's not organised the way you want it, is to re-organize it. I'd merge the two lists adding the display name to each user. But, of course, you see immediately that that's not necessary as each user already contains their display name. (The `displayNames` branch of your json is unnecessary for your purposes.)

So, you can just work with the `users` branch. Note that what you are doing is extracting the members of the `users` list and subtly changing the tag name (from `displayName` to `name` - leaving `photoURL` the same). Is the tag name change necessary? If not you could basically achieve what you want with a single `where`.

That said, this should achieve what you want (including the tag name change):

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProfilesBySuggestion(
    String sSuggestion) async {
  try {
    if (sSuggestion == null ||
        sSuggestion.isEmpty ||
        !sSuggestion.startsWith('@')) return [];

    //Getting all the names
    Map<String, dynamic> allUsers = await getAllUsers();
    if (allUsers == null) return [];

    //Returning only the names corresponding
    List<dynamic> users = allUsers['users'];

    var suffix = sSuggestion.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    return users
        .where((user) => user['displayName'].toLowerCase().startsWith(suffix))
        .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((user) => {
              'name': user['displayName'],
              'photoURL': user['photoURL'],
            })
        .toList();
  } catch (error) {
    print('*** Error During getProfilesBySuggestion: ${error.toString()}');
    return [
      {'errorMessage': error.toString()}
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that does the trick!<br/><br/>

The tag name was not that necessary indeed, so this was enough:<br/><br/>


```dart
return users
        .where((user) => user['displayName'].toLowerCase().startsWith(suffix)).toList();
```


The initial DisplayNames list was for a use case where only the names were needed (suggestion box a la Facebook/Twitter where you @ someone, and indeed more than the names are needed).


Thanks again!

Comment: You won't have performance problems unless your json is enormous. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> A good starting point when working with data that's not organised the way you want it, is to re-organize it.

And if that's not an option, you can still mitigate the impact. It's always easier to work with plain old dart classes than json, so I'd encourage you to map the json to classes.

I usually use [package:built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) for that. There is a tool that helps map json: 
https://charafau.github.io/json2builtvalue/ *Careful*, it's not 100%. Eg. it will not include `photoUrl` field if you just copy-paste your json.

Basically, I'd take the `json.users`, and map it to objects. Make sure to make `photoUrl` optional.

Once that's done, you can create any lookup table you want. You could just have a `List<User>` to iterate over names and photoUrls, or you could create a `Map<String, User>` to look up users by their name.

*Tip:* [class Map](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map-class.html) has got a number of constructors that you can work with.

Comment: Thanks. Same comment as below, json to dart classes, does that help with scale and performace? I feel as if I am adding extra work, knowing that my application will run in emerging countries on mostly not as performant smartphones as in the "developed" world. Thanks!